# Excel VBA Combo Chart with different Excel versions (2010 vs 2016)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that seems to behave differently between Office 2010 and Office 2016, specifically the "combo chart" function. (we are in a transition between Office 2010 (Win7) and Office 2016 (Win10)).

What I would like to figure out is how to develop a function in our macro to "sense" if the users is opening the macro in 2010 or 2016 (if that is possible) and execute the "create chart" subs

When I originally developed the macro in 2016, this is the sub to create the combo chart.

```
'' Create ComboChart (Excel2016only)
'
    Range("A1:C11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$C$11")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
```

When a 2010 user attempts to run this, it will "Compile error: Method or data member not found" at .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered. I believe its because combo charts were not native until 2016.

Therefore I had to manually record macro steps to figure out how to do secondary axis in 2010 as its not native.

```
' ComboChartExcel2010 Macro
'
    Range("A1:C11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$C$11")
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
```

Any suggestions to develop a routine where it can run either subs based on the Excel version the user is running? For now I have to have a UI box asking the user to select which one they are running.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `Application.Version` will tell you the version of Excel you're/they're using.

`IF Application.Version = 15 Then` ... you're using Excel 2013

12 = Excel 2007

14 = Excel 2010

15 = Excel 2013

16 = Excel 2016

Comment: I tried: 'code' If Application.Version = 16 Then
    Range("A1:C11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$C$11")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered 'code' but the Excel2010 debugger still does not recognize it.

Comment: Sorry, your question suggested that you had the code working, but based on the user selecting which version they had. This solution removes the need to ask the user no?

Answer (score 0):

This is doing well in  Excel 2010.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$C$11")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
```

Comment: at 2010  there is not .AddChart2.